# Generate XML using input XML with help of XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestCode version="10.0">
    <TestCategory name="SmokeTest">
        <Test name="CheckType_123"  type="String">
            <Test_description>No description available for this Test</Test_description>
            <context name="Testing">
                <value>ABC</value>
                <value>XYZ</value>
            </context>
        </Test>
        <Test name="CheckType_PQR"  type="String">
            <Test_description>No description available for this Test</Test_description>
            <context name="SmokeTest">
                <value>ABC</value>
            </context>
        </Test>
        <Test name="ValueAdded_123"  type="String">
            <Test_description>No description available for this Test</Test_description>
            <context name="Testing">
                <value>ABC</value>
                <value>XYZ</value>
            </context>
        </Test>
    </TestCategory>
</TestCode>
```

From the above xml file, I need to check if i have tag <Test name=CheckType_* and if yes, i need to check if i have context/vlaue = XYZ. If exist i need to take the whole <Test ...>  tag and put it in a new xml file.

So from the above xml, the output what i need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestCode version="10.0">
    <TestCategory name="SmokeTest">
        <Test name="CheckType_123"  type="String">
            <Test_description>No description available for this Test</Test_description>
            <context name="Testing">
                <value>ABC</value>
                <value>XYZ</value>
            </context>
        </Test>
    </TestCategory>
</TestCode>
```

because from my input xml, the second Test tag has no value XYZ and 3rd Test tag has no name starting with CheckType_*. Can you help me with this?

Thank You

Comment: What did you encounter and/or where did you get stuck? Please post your XSLT code as well.

Comment: I am new to xslt. My actual requirement is to do it with powershell but somehwere i read that xslt is better so seeking some help here

Answer (score 0):

Start with identity cask transform which can easily found on internet and then create 2 template :

- one to remove Test
- other to copy Test if conditions match

  <xsl:template match="Test"/>

  <xsl:template match="Test[starts-with(´CheckType_’)][context/value='XYZ']">

  ```
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  ```

  </xsl:template>

Note : sorry for the formatting .